# MongoDB $in and "like" - getting records that have zip codes LIKE what is in a n array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection of addresses, with postal codes.
I want to get all the records by using an array of postal codes

so this query works fine

```
db.getCollection('addresses').find({"address.postal_code":{$in:['40475','37214']}})
```

This is great if all my postal codes are exactly 5 digits...
But some people enter the plus 4 - so I might have an address with '37214-3724'
which wouldn't get returned...

a different use case might be "last_name"

```
db.getCollection('names').find({"last_name":{$in:['Smith','Johnson']}})
```

when I want to make sure I get all derivation of Smith, Smiths, Smithson, Smithback, Smithy... etc. OR Johnson, Johnsonville, Johsonstonson... etc

The postal code is the use case at hand, I just thru in the last name, so someone doesn't say "just limit your input to 5 digits..." (missing the point of the question)

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expression (regex) like in the following example.

**Sample documents:**

```
{ "_id" : 1, "name" : "Johnson" }
{ "_id" : 2, "name" : "John" }
{ "_id" : 3, "name" : "Johnston" }
{ "_id" : 4, "name" : "Smith" }
{ "_id" : 5, "name" : "Smithy" }
{ "_id" : 9, "name" : "James" }
```

**Query the collection using regex:**

```
db.regex1.find({ name: { $in: [ /^Smith/, /^John/ ] } } )
```

*Result:* This query will get the five documents with `_id`s 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.

This following query will get all the Smiths (`_id`s 4 and 5):

```
db.regex1.find({ name: /^Smith/ })
```

**NOTES**:

1. *The postal codes* (e.g., "40475" and "40475-3724") can be matched in similar way, as in the example above.
2. There is also a [$regex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/index.html) operator which can be used for querying, but it *doesn't work* with the `$in`.